# Como usar un dominio en lugar de una IP en Java

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación que funciona muy bien en `Local(área local)` pero cuando lo uso fuera de mi Red Local, no puedo porque necesito usar un dominio. Entonces quería editarlo y hacerlo funcional para que funcione desde fuera de `LAN`. Intente usando `InetAddress` y haciendo lo siguiente:

```
public LauncherActivity()
        throws UnknownHostException
        {
            this.giriAddress=InetAddress.getByName("MIDOMINIO");
            System.out.println("EJEMPLO"+giriAddress);

        }
```

El problema es que solamente me lo lanza cuando se produce la excepción y quería que mi programa fuera capaz de obtener `LA IP DE MI DOMINIO` para poder conectarse. Entonces pensé en quitarle la parte de `throws UnknownHostException` pero me devolvió el siguiente error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unhandled exception type UnknownHostException   LauncherActivity.java   //src/my/app/client line 33 Java Problem
```

Entonces mi pregunta es como podría hacer para que mi programa coja la ip de mi dominio(solamente me lo hace cuando lanzo la excepción sino me devuelve error) y me conecte como si usará mi `IP Habitual`.
En mi caso el programa completo sería:

```
package my.app.client;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import my.app.client.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LauncherActivity extends Activity
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        Intent Client, ClientAlt;
        // Button btnStart, btnStop;
        // EditText ipfield, portfield;
        private InetAddress giriAddress;

        public LauncherActivity()

        {
            this.giriAddress=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
            System.out.println("EJEMPLO"+giriAddress);

        }   
        //private String hostIP = giriAddress.getHostAddress() ;
        private String myIp = "IP"; // Put your IP in these quotes.
        private int myPort = 12; // Put your port there, notice that there are no quotes here.

        @Override
        public void onStart()
            {
                super.onStart();
                onResume();
            }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
            {
                super.onResume();
                Client = new Intent(this, Client.class);
                Client.setAction(LauncherActivity.class.getName());
                getConfig();
                Client.putExtra("IP", myIp);
                Client.putExtra("PORT", myPort);

                startService(Client);
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//              setContentView(R.layout.main);
                Client = new Intent(this, Client.class);
                Client.setAction(LauncherActivity.class.getName());
                getConfig();
                Client.putExtra("IP", myIp);
                Client.putExtra("PORT", myPort);

                startService(Client);
                //moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
        /**
         * get Config
         */
        private void getConfig()
            {
                Properties pro = new Properties();
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.config);
                try
                    {
                        pro.load(is);
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                myIp = pro.getProperty("host");
                myPort = Integer.valueOf(pro.getProperty("prot"));
                System.out.println(myIp);
                System.out.println(myPort);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La aplicación parece correcta.
El error    `Unhandled exception type UnknownHostException`   se debe a una excepción no manejada, intenta ponerlo dentro de un `Try-catch`:

```
try {
    this.giriAddress=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
    System.out.println("EJEMPLO "+giriAddress);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // manejo de error
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hola dentro de mi clase tengo esto, tengo primero mi clase, y como me devolvia unhandled exception puse la clase dentro de mi misma clase así `private InetAddress giriAddress;

        public LauncherActivity()
        {
             try {
     this.giriAddress=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
     System.out.println("EJEMPLO "+giriAddress);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
             
         
            
        }`, pero nunca me imprime consola EJEMPLO + ""

Comment: Hola, es raro, ya que el constructor siempre se ejecuta primero y que además no salte algún error por alguna otra excepción. Podrías intentar colocar todo ese fragmento de `InetAddress` dentro del método `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

No debes quitar la cláusula  throws UnknownHostException, es correcta.
Si el código esta arrojando esa Exception es porque no encontró el dominio. Chequea tu DNS en tu configuración de red.
Prueba desde una consola de comandos el comando ping midominio para ver si tienes acceso al dominio.